# Error with apps in App Engine and Google Vault api

Tags: google-vault-api

I need some help with my App Engine apps. I have two aplications, one of them in php and the other in python (both do the same thing). These applications show a list of matters and exports with google vault api, but after two or three calls to the api these apps stay in a state of loading and i get a 500 error, returned by App Engine, but I have a feeling that it is a Google Vault Api  problem. Sometimes these work well, but if I reload the pages I get the same error. Do you know if there is a problem with App Engine and Google Vault Api?

Some times a get the error calling listMatters  method:

```
try{

  $client = getClient();
  $service = new Google_Service_Vault($client);

  $optParams = array(
        'pageSize' => 100
      );
  $results = $service->matters->listMatters($optParams);
  $matters = $results->getMatters();
  
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die(var_dump($e->getMessage()));
}
```

Other times calling listMattersExports method:

```
try {
            $client = getClient();
     $service = new Google_Service_Vault($client);
        
                $resultsExports = $service->matters_exports->listMattersExports($matterId,$optParams);
                $exports = $resultsExports->getExports();
        
        
           }catch  (Exception $e){
               die(var_dump($e->getMessage()));
           }
```

The problem is I get 500 error, but no an Api error.

Comment: This is the status of the Google Cloud services: https://status.cloud.google.com/

Comment: Could you please provide the code related to the API calls?

Comment: ok, question updated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error when using Vault API by itself. Have you tried these API calls [via Try this API](https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/matters.exports/list) or [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)? I'm thinking the problem could be related to App Engine instead.

Comment: Hi @lamblichus, yes I tried but the calls work fine this way. My problem was App Engine and Vault Api. Yesterday magically my apps started working fine and today I have no problem. I did nothing to resolve this. It is very strange behavior.